# Non-trivial solutions in PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In the following question I am trying to find a non trivial solution to the following partial differential equations by inspection and integrating, where many solutions may be possible

1) $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + 2yu = 0 $$

So here my thinking is just to move $2yu$ to the right side of the equation and solve this DE which is just linear,

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -2yu$$
$$P(x) = -2x$$
$$Q(x) = 0 $$
$$e^{\int -2ydy} = e^{-y^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} e^{-y^2} = -2yu\cdot e^{-y^2}$$
$$u = \int-2yu\cdot e^{-y^2}dy$$

Then how would I solve this integral? and I am not sure if this is correct since it says to solve by inspection and integration

2) $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}=0 $$

I am not sure what to do with this equation, if you integrated wouldn't you just get a constant C?

Comment: For $(2)$, no, integration gives you an arbitrary _function_ of the other variable. i.e $$u_{xy} = 0 \implies u_{x} = f(x)$$

Comment: @Mattos then how do I find a non trivial solution?

Comment: Integrate now with respect to $x$..

Comment: so then $u_x=x+c$?

Comment: sorry your workings just appeared now with the text

Comment: No, $u_{x} = f(x)$ where $f$ is arbitrary. Integrating now with respect to $x$ yields

$$\int u_{x} dx = \int f dx \implies u = \int f dx + g(y)$$

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. I just gave you the answer.

$$u = \int f(x) dx + g(y)$$

for arbitrary $f$ and $g$ satisfies $u_{xy} = 0$.

Comment: I was a little confused, but got it now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This reduces to 
$$ \frac{1}{2y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + u = 0$$

So we can get away with some old school tricks

$$ \frac{1}{2y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + u = 0 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -u  \rightarrow \frac{1}{u} \partial u = -2y \partial y$$

Yielding

$$ \ln(u) = -2y^2 + F(x) $$ 
$$  u = e^{F(x) - 2y^2} $$

For any $F(x)$ of your choice. Example

$$ u = e^{e^x - 2y^2} $$

Is one solution

Comment: Isn't $\ln(u)=-y^2+F(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + 2yu = 0 \tag 1$$

Since there is no differential wrt $x$ in the equation, $x$ can be considered as a parameter. For each value of $x$, Eq.$(1)$ is no longer a PDE but is an ODE :
$$\frac{du}{dy} + 2yu = 0$$
You know how to solve this separable ODE :
$$u=C\:e^{-y^2} $$
$C$ can be different for each value of $x$. Thus, in fact, $C$ is an arbitrary function of $x$.

The general solution of Eq.$(1)$ is
$$u(x,y)=F(x)\:e^{-y^2} $$ 
where $F(x)$ is an arbitrary function.
$$ $$
$$ $$

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}=0 \tag 2$$
Let $\quad v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \quad\to\quad \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0 \tag 3$$
Since there is no differential wrt $x$ in the equation, $x$ can be considered as a parameter. For each value of $x$, Eq.$(3)$ is no longer a PDE but is an ODE :
$$\frac{dv}{dy} = 0$$
$$v=C $$
$C$ can be different for each value of $x$. Thus, in fact, $C$ is an arbitrary function of $x$.
$$v(x,y)=f(x)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f(x) \tag 4$$
Since there is no differential wrt $y$ in the equation, $y$ can be considered as a parameter. For each value of $y$, Eq.$(4)$ is no longer a PDE but is an ODE :
$$\frac{du}{dx}=f(x)$$
Integrating wrt $x$ gives :
$$u=\int f(x)dx+c$$
$f(x)$ is an arbitrary function, thus $F(x)=\int f(x)dx$ is an arbitrary function.

$c$ can be different for each value of $y$. Thus, in fact, $c$ is an arbitrary function of $y$, say $G(y)$.
$$u(x,y)=F(x)+G(y)$$
where $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary functions.

Comment: thanks for your submission! since there are many possibilities of solutions, is the other answer posted correct also for question 1)?

Comment: I don't agree with $  u = e^{F(x) - 2y^2} $. I agree with $  u = e^{F(x) - y^2} $. Since $F$ is arbitrary, this is the same as $  u = f(x)e^{ - y^2} $  with $f(x)=e^{F(x)}$.

Comment: okay I will look at your answer then, thanks!